# Heter to decorate the shul in a humorous way in Adar?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, kavod, adar

I am bias here, I was raised to treat a beit k'neset (shul) with utmost respect; not to use the sanctuary as a shortcut, avoid mundane discussions there etc. I now live in a community which festively decorates the sanctuary of the shul in honor of the advent of Adar with all manner of frivolity. I would like to know what the poskim say in regards to this practice? Is it permitted and if so why (meaning why is it not a p'gam in the kavod of a beit k'neset)?

Comment: If it raises the spirits of the congregants and helps their kavana then no.

Comment: @DavidFeigen is this a typo or sarcasm? I guess I am a little dense right now.

Comment: I would suggest you ask the Rabbi in a respectful way as to why it is done.